# Adding dynamic content inside a shopify store page

Tags: shopify, content-management-system, shopify-template

I have a case in which I would like to create a knowledge base for my products. For this, I want to create an informative page for each product category. The 1st goal is to find out the optimal way of using the provided Shopify tools(blogs and pages) instead of a 3rd party CMS. The 2nd goal is to decouple Shopify template code from the content so that developers and content editors are able to work independently.

At the the moment I have 3 categories, cat1, cat2 and cat3. Each category has multiple sections, slightly different from each other (most categories have the same sections). Some of the sections are:

- Intro
- History
- Nutritional information
  .....

Since I need an easy way for the content editors to manage the available content (text and images related to the categories), I thought of organising my content into blogs, one for each category. As mentioned, the main goal here to allow content editors to work smoothly in a rich text editor instead of forcing them to use the Shopify template UI. Then the structure of the blogs/categories looks as next:

- Cat1

  - Intro
  - History
  - Nutritional information
  - ...
- Cat2

  - Intro
  - History
  - Nutritional information
  - Cat2 special section
  - ....
- Cat3

  - Intro
  - History
  - Nutritional information
  - Cat3 special section1
  - Cat3 special section2
  - .....

As for the shopify UI, I thought of having one template/page for each category (since each category will have different sections).

The way this should work is by loading the right blog dynamically and serve it to the corresponding page by using a code similar to the one shown [here](https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/dynamically-load-blog-content-into-a-product-page/td-p/1658475). For each category page we fill in its sections by loading the corresponding blog posts.

Is this approach correct? Should I organise my category sections into blog posts as described above, or there is a more efficient way to handle our content?